# Put class intervals within the graph in a histogram, for example as a legend

Tags: r, histogram

The actual version of my code is :

```
hist_Price <- hist(diamonds$price)
hist(x = diamonds$price,
     main = "HIstograma del Precio de los Diamantes (Dataset : diamonds)",
     col="blue",
     ylim = c(0,max(hist_Price$counts)+2000),
     xaxt = 'n' # necesario para el uso de la funcion text()
)
axis(side = 1,at = seq(0,max(diamonds$price),3000))
text(hist_Price$mids,hist_Price$counts,labels=hist_Price$counts, adj=c(0.5, -0.5))
box()
```

I'm looking for a way to put class intervals within the graph, for example as a legend. maybe as it appears in this graph

[image: Example]

Obviously, with R the graph should look more professional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code requires 19 different colors. It is hard to distinguish that many colors so I am cutting it down to 10. Otherwise just use the legend function.

```
library(ggplot2)    ## for diamonds data
hist_Price = hist(x = diamonds$price,
    breaks = seq(0,20000, 2000),
     main = "Histograma del Precio de los Diamantes (Dataset : diamonds)",
     col=rainbow(10, end=0.85),
     ylim = c(0,max(hist_Price$counts)+2000),
     xaxt = 'n' # necesario para el uso de la funcion text()
)
axis(side = 1,at = seq(0,max(diamonds$price),2000))
text(hist_Price$mids,hist_Price$counts,labels=hist_Price$counts, adj=c(0.5, -0.5))
box()

LABELS = paste(seq(0,18000, 2000), seq(2000,20000, 2000), sep="-")
legend("topright", legend=LABELS, fill=rainbow(10, end=0.85))
```

[image: Histogram with legend]

Note that I resized the image after displaying.

Comment: Thx G5W, I appreciate your help .